# jQuery plugin not working Chrome (sometimes). Works good in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I added to a website a plugin that shows a calendar and the user can choose several days. It works fine on Firefox, but it does not execute on Chrome and Opera. The strange thing is that I isolated the plugin in another website, just with this code:

```
<title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
<style type="text/css">
    @import "jquery.datepick.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.lang.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick-es.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $('#popupDatepicker').datepick({multiSelect: 999, monthsToShow: 2,dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd', showTrigger: '<button id="showcal" type="button" class="trigger    ">' +
     '<img src="img/calendar.gif" alt="Calendario"></button>'});
         //$.datepick.regional['es']));
 });



</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>A popup datepicker <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker"></p>
```

Which is the minimum code to get the plugin working and it does work in Chrome (plugin site here)[1](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

The problem is when I implement it on the complete website, which doesn't work. It is the same code with the same libraries included, but obviously with other code.

I have checked firebug and it does not return any error, so I am a bit lost.

Just in case in needed, my Chrome version is 18.0.1025.162, but should not be relevant.

What can be wrong?

One last thing: Is there any kind of javascript standard which would work on all browsers?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Which `plugin` you used.. I mean the resource that you have used

Comment: Try from here as you are doing multiselect http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html Select `multiple` tab and check out

Comment: "... any kind of javascript standard...," really?!? Ever heard of ECMAScript?

Comment: @User I used that library.
Alexander Sorry for my lack of knowledge. Don't need to be like that.

Comment: If you are using that script means it should work why because I am using that script from years in my application no issues for me

Comment: @User yes, that is what I do not understand, if I put the example code of the website on a "clean" website, it works flawlessly, but if I put that chunk of code in my production site, does not work

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has an excellent datepicker and is a good bet to be compatible with most browsers.

Comment: I checked that datepicker, but it does not allow me (as far as I know) to pick several days, for example: day 1, day 4, day 20, day 22.